# Recuperar valor de um option dentro de uma função each

Tags: jquery, html-select, each

Eu tenho um html e um script em Jquery que adiciona telefones a um cadastro de clientes dinamicamente. Estou tentando colocar máscaras de dois tipos diferentes para cada tipo de telefone que possa ser cadastrado. Porém ao percorrer os elementos inseridos dinamicamente não estou conseguindo recuperar o valor do select para saber qual máscara colocar.

Meu HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Olá, mundo!</h1>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Telefones</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-add-telefone">Adicionar telefone</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8" id="div-telefones">

    </div>                
  </div>
</div>
```

Meu script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var qtdTelefones = 0;

$("#btn-add-telefone").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var blocoTelefone = '<div class="row mb-2">' +
        '    <div class="col-md-2">' +
        '        <input type="cel" name="Telefones[' + qtdTelefones + '].DDD" maxlength="2" placeholder="DDD" class="form-control txt-ddd" />' +
        '    </div>' +
        '    <div class="col-md-6">' +
        '        <input type="text" name="Telefones[' + qtdTelefones + '].Numero" maxlength="9" placeholder="Número" class="form-control txt-numero" />' +
        '    </div>' +
        '    <div class="col-md-3 tipos-telefones">' +
        '        <select name="Telefones[' + qtdTelefones + '].tipoTelefone" class="form-control sel-tipo">' +
        '            <option value="0">Celular</option>' +
        '            <option value="1">Residencial</option>' +
        '            <option value="2">Comercial</option>' +
        '        </select>' +
        '    </div>' +
        '    <div class="col-md-1">' +
        '        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-remover-telefone">Excluir' +
        '        </button>' +
        '    </div>' +
        '</div>';
    
    $("#div-telefones").append(blocoTelefone);
    qtdTelefones++;
    $(".txt-numero").mask("99999-9999");
});


$("#div-telefones").on("change", ".sel-tipo", function () { 

    $(".tipos-telefones").each(function (indice, elemento) {
        var opcao = $(".sel-tipo option:selected").val();

        alert("Valor da repetição: " + indice + "elemento: " + elemento.innerHTML);            
        alert("Valor do drop: " + opcao);
    });        
    
});
});
```

Comment: @Sam pode formalizar um exemplo para ficar mais claro? Obrigado!
O valor recuperado, independente de quantos elementos forem criados, sempre retorna o primeiro em todas as iterações.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está nessa linha aqui:

```
var opcao = $(".sel-tipo option:selected").val();
```

Vai retornar sempre o valor do primeiro `select` que possui a classe `.sel-tipo` (mais especificamente, o `option` selecionado) porque não foi especificado **qual deles** se houver mais de um, porém é redundante usar `option:selected` nesse caso pois o `.val()` já retorna o valor do `option` selecionado. Nesse caso, se fosse só um elemento, bastaria apenas usar `$(".sel-tipo").val()`.

Mas como podem ser mais de um elemento, é preciso especificar, em cada volta do `.each()`, qual deles você quer pegar o valor, ou seja, o valor do `select` contido dentro da `div` atual em cada iteração do laço.

Aí você pode fazer de duas formas. Uma usando [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var opcao = $(elemento).find(".sel-tipo").val();
ou
var opcao = $(".sel-tipo", elemento).val(); // forma abreviada
```

Ou pelo índice, usando [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), já que cada índice de `.tipos-telefones` é o mesmo do `select.sel-tipo` contido nele:

```
var opcao = $(".sel-tipo").eq(indice).val();
```

Comment: Consegui fazer @Sam. Agradeço a sua ajuda e feedback!
O meu código ficou assim:

` $("#div-telefones").on("change", ".sel-tipo", function () { 
        $("#div-telefones .row").each(function (indice, elemento) {
            var opcao = $(elemento).find(".sel-tipo").val();
            if (opcao == '0'){
                $(elemento).find(".txt-numero").mask("99999-9999");
            }
            else{
                $(elemento).find(".txt-numero").mask("9999-9999");
            }
        });
});

Abraços!

Comment: Que bom amigo. Fico feliz. Abs!